# Add overlay on specific images selected (no more than 3)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a grid of cards, right now clicking one of the cards adds an overlay to all of them.

I need:

1.-  If user clicks one cards, and only that card gets the overlay.
2.-  No more than 3 cards at a time can have an overlay. User would have to click one of the already clicked cards to diselect it, in order to select another one.

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/yLJGzYr

**JS Code:**

```
$('.imageDiv').click(function(){
    $('img').toggleClass("tricky_image");
    $(".text").toggleClass("display-inline");
});
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Make use of `this` so that the relevant scope is preserved.

```
$('.imageDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass("tricky_image");
    /*$(".text").css("display", "inline");*/
    $(this).find(".text").toggleClass("display-inline");
});
```

You could equally (maybe) use the `.children()` method (as opposed to `.find()`) but I didn't know exactly how your dom structure was inside each "imageDiv".

Comment: what about selecting only 3 cards at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Your specified click function search for every 'img' element and every node with a .text class.

What you actually want, is to get the child img element and .text of the clicked .imageDiv
By limiting the queried scope with $(this).find(...) we only search for child elements of the clicked .imageDiv.

With some additional logic your second requirement can be also fulfilled ->

```
$('.imageDiv').click(function(){
    const trickyCount = $(".tricky_image").length;
    const img = $(this).find('img');
    const text = $(this).find(".text");
    if(trickyCount < 3 || img.hasClass("tricky_image")){
      img.toggleClass("tricky_image");
      text.toggleClass("display-inline");  
    }
});
```